# tkinter Text widget does not print input data

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to get input through tkinter text widget. I saw posts about tkinter text widget input. But those didn't work for me. I saw post on  and tried that but I couldn't understand what is wrong with it. Here is my code.

```
`corpusinput = Text(rooter, width=50, height=10)
 corpustext = corpusinput.get("1.0", "end-1c")
 corpusinput.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='nsew')
 print(corpustext)`
```

This prints a blank space/line without any character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the `.get()` method on the widget just after you've created it. At this point the widget is blank, so `.get()` will return`''`.

You need to setup a way of calling `.get()` whilst the program is running, eg. a button

```
corpusinput = Text(rooter, width=50, height=10)
corpusinput.grid()

get_input = Button(rooter, text='Print', command= lambda x=corpusinput.get() : print(x))
get_input.grid()
```